# List of independent RadioGroups

Tags: android, list, listview, radio-group

I've looked for solution to my problem everywhere but mine is kind of specific...I need an advice on how to create list of independent radioGroups such as illustrated:

### o item1     • item1'

### • item2     o item2'

### o item3     • item3'

In what kind of object would I store those radiogroups and how do I generate them. Also radioButtons would be generated dynamically. Do I use listview or I don't need it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider using a vertical linear layout, then placing the radiogroups as the child elements, like so

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="RadioButton" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="RadioButton" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and you'll end up with a layout like you described.